# Phase space volume for multiple particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, phase-space

How do I calculate the phase space volume for an ensemble of more than one (in this particular case, three) free moving particle with the same mass $m$ moving in one dimension? I do understand how to calculate it for a single particle, more or less, but from the examples I've got at hand it doesn't seem like a simple matter of adding each individual volume